# Java Reading a txt that has different numbers in its column file and store data in an arraylist

Tags: java, file, arraylist, split, txt

Hello Guys I have a txt file below, I need to store the second column data but it gives me an error since some lines have 1 some have 2 and some have 3 input in each line. How can I solve that problem?

```
5
3 4
3 4
3 3
3 4
3 3
3 4
3 3
3 2
3 4
3 3
3 2
3 1
3 4
3 3
3 2
3 1
3 0
1
2
5 3 4
3 4
3 4
3 3
3 4
3 3
3 4
3 3
3 2
3 4
3 3
3 2
3 1
3 4
3 3
3 2
3 1
3 0
1
2
5 4 6
4 4
4 4
4 4
4 4
4 4
4 4
4 3
4 3
4 3
4 3
4 4
4 4
1
2
5 4 6
0
```

Here is what I did, I tried to differentiate as the size and in the other way but still cant get the answer...

```
String line = "";

ArrayList<String> numbers= new ArrayList<String>();

try {

    String sCurrentLine;
    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input1.txt"));
    int n = 0;

    while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] arr = sCurrentLine.split(" ");
        int size = arr.length;

        List<String> list = ConvertToList.convertArrayToList(arr);
        List<Integer> listOfInteger = convert.convertStringListToIntList(list, Integer::parseInt);
        if (list.size() == 2) {
            line.split("\\s+");
            numbers.add(line.split("\\s+")[0]);
            System.out.println(numbers);
        }
    }
} catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to split the line again. When you split the line first time, check if the length of the resulting array is `2`. If yes, add `arr[1]` to `numbers`.

```
while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] arr = sCurrentLine.split(" ");                
    if (arr.length >= 2) {
        numbers.add(arr[1]);
        System.out.println(numbers);
    }
}
```

### Update:

Based on your comment, I am providing you following code which uses your lists:

```
while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] arr = sCurrentLine.split(" ");
    List<String> list = ConvertToList.convertArrayToList(arr);
    List<Integer> listOfInteger = convert.convertStringListToIntList(list, Integer::parseInt);
    if (listOfInteger.size() >= 2) {
        numbers.add(listOfInteger.get(1));
    }          
}
System.out.println(numbers);
```

You can keep `System.out.println(numbers);` inside or outside the `while` loop depending on how you want to print `numbers`.

Comment: Shouldn't it be if (arr.length >= 2)

Comment: @rishavprasher - The requirement is: `I need to store the second column data...`

Comment: but after split length can we greater than 2. e.g. if it is 3 even then we have to store the number at the 2nd column right?

Comment: @rishavprasher - You are right. Updated the answer.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash I posted a new code that how my code works when I tried your suggestion. Can you seee them?

Comment: @SabuhaRajanKaya - I've added an update on your request. Feel free to comment in case of any doubt/issue.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash Thank you so much that was a great help. Have a nice day:)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read and save only the second column than you get the data in second column by using the index 1. (After your while loop.)

```
String secondCol = sCurrentLine.split(" ")[1];
```

In case you don't have a value in 2 column than it will throw and exception which you should handle with simple try catch.
Finally convert it to int and store in your list. with following.

```
listOfInteger.add(Integer.parseInt(secoundCol));
```

Hopefully it will work.